# Measure code complexity in clojure

Tags: clojure

In Ruby, there are several tools to calculate complexity of the code, for example the cyclomatic complexity, the ABC score or flog, as described here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/08/07/deciphering-ruby-code-metrics/

Are there similar tools calculate the complexity of functions and/or entire namespaces in clojure?

Answer (score 9):

To expand on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365729/how-to-calculate-cyclomatic-complexity-of-a-clojure-function) to a similar question: Homoiconicity in Clojure makes it [quite easy](https://github.com/lokori/uncomplexor/blob/master/src/leiningen/uncomplexor.clj) to calculate basic code complexity measures.

That said, I wouldn't bother. The biggest sources of complexity in beginner Clojure programs come from wrong things, not structurally complex things. For example, programmers coming from a language like Ruby that encourages unstructured mutation are likely to initially:

- [overuse dynamic vars](https://stuartsierra.com/2013/03/29/perils-of-dynamic-scope)
- [use def](https://twitter.com/stuartsierra/status/519556110731460608) for things that should be function args
- use setters when updaters are the correct semantic
- wait too long before learning [core.async](http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html)

Interestingly, many of these mistakes might also be flagged by automatic analysis.